# ProbabilityTheory, precise definition of r.vs with same distribution

Tags: probability-theory

Studying probability theory, I wonder the definition of 
$X \overset{d}{=}Y$.

However, it took me long time to search it to find nothing.

Considering in the extension of limit law, i.e $X_n \to_d X$,

I could think it like this so far;

$F_X(t)=F_Y(t)$ for all $t \in C$ where $C$ is a dense subset in $\mathbb{R}$.

Can this be a sufficient answer?

Comment: If that is the case for a dense subset $C\subset\mathbb R$ then also for $\mathbb R$ itself so $F_X=F_Y$, i.e. $X\overset{d}{=}Y$ by definition. Does this answer your question completely?

Comment: @drhab So.. you define $X \overset{d}{=} Y$ by $F_X(t)=F_Y(t)$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$. Right? //and thanks for a comment

Comment: Yes, $X \overset{d}{=}Y$ means that the random variable have equal *distribution* wich can also be expressed by saying that they have equal cumulative distribution function. You are welcome.

Comment: However, I concern about discontinuities of the cumulative distribution, which is overcome by continuity set in convergence of distribution. i.e $X_n \to_d X$ iff $F_{X_n}(t) \to F_X(t)$ for all $t \in C_F$ where $C_F$ is the set of continuity w.r.t $F$. I'd like to hear your opinion.

Comment: $X_n \to_d X$ is normally defined as: $F_{X_n}(t)\to F_X(t)$ for every $t$ where $F_X$ is continuous.

Comment: Yes, as you said just above, I don't think it has to be the whole $\mathbb{R}$ where $F_X$ equals $F_Y$.

Comment: The statements '$F_X=F_Y$' and '$F_X(t)=F_Y(t)$ on a dense $C$' are *equivalent*. If the second is true then the first is true, so in that sense "it has to be the whole $\mathbb R$".

Comment: OK, I understand. Thanks so much